# How to control image on the before/after css psuedo element

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a hard time making an image with a psuedo element

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <h1>TESTING</h1>
      </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here's the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('./Path\ 14@2x.png');
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 30% 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Here's how the code looks when you see it:
[image]

I want the image to take 100% of the width instead of repeating like that maybe the image is too small but I can't find a bigger image

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQEdW.jpg)

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Image link doesn't work for me. Can you provide a proper one please

Comment: make background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I added `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and then change the background size to  `background-size: 100% 100%;`

See working example here:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/TEKMxzx.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <h1>TESTING</h1>
      </section>
</body>
</html>
```